# Php Mysqli Error

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$sql4="update packages set
expiry='".$pkg_expiry."' , featured_agent_logo='".$pkg_Featured_Logo."' , ads_banner='".$pkg_Ads_Banner."' ,    web_url='".$pkg_website."' , watermark='".$pkg_watermark."' , video='".$pkg_video."' , featured_properties='".$pkg_featured_prop."' , new_listings='".$pkg_newlisting."' , hot_listing='".$pkg_hotlisting."' , sponsored_list='".$pkg_sponsoredlisting."' , messages='".$pkg_message."'
WHERE pkg_id = $pkgid";
```

Is there any error in my query ? because it isn't working it gives me an error and the error is :-

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 7

Comment: Could you echo the statement and share the result with us?

Comment: 45
0
0
1
1
0
0
0
0
0
0

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7

Comment: Please share the final SQL once the variables have been substituted ( ie: echo $sql4 )

Comment: update packages set expiry = '45
' ,featured_agent_logo = '0
' ,ads_banner = '0
', web_url = '1
' ,watermark = '1
',video = '0
' , featured_properties = '0
' ,new_listings = '0
' ,hot_listing = '0
' ,sponsored_list = '0
' , messages = '0
' where pkg_id = You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7

Comment: It seems $pkg_id has no value. The WHERE is empty.

Comment: Every variable is outside the quotes. Except for the last one. Why? Also use capitals. And you curious... Why do I see whitespace after every INT Integer, (I guess)

Comment: yes it's not picking the value of $pkg_id i don't know why . @AnthonyB

Comment: Can you show all your code in the question ? During $pkf_id initialization you're trying to use a value that is null, probably.

Comment: Dear @KoenHollander all the variables are inside the quotes because all the variable have the boolean value thats why i keep it in the quotes

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_GET['update_ids']) // query string
    {
                        $update_id=$_GET['update_ids'];
                        $que="select * from packages where pkg_id=$update_id ";
                        $display=mysqli_query($con,$que)or die(mysqli_error($con));
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($display)){
                            $id = $row['pkg_id'];
                            $pkg_name=$row['package_name'];
                            $pkg_price=$row['package_price'];
                            $pkg_credits=$row['credits'];
                            $pkg_expiry=$row['expiry'];
                            $pkg_Featured_Logo=$row['featured_agent_logo'];
                            $pkg_Ads_Banner=$row['ads_banner'];
                            $pkg_website=$row['web_url'];
                            $pkg_watermark=$row['watermark'];
                            $pkg_video=$row['video'];
                            $pkg_featured_prop=$row['featured_properties'];
                            $pkg_newlisting=$row['new_listings'];
                        //  $pkg_auction=$row['auction'];
                        //  $pkg_projects=$row['projects'];
                            $pkg_hotlisting=$row['hot_listing'];
                            $pkg_sponsoredlisting=$row['sponsored_list'];
                            $pkg_message=$row['messages'];
                        }
    }
                    ?>
```

And i have 2 forms

```
<form  class="form-horizontal form-label-left input_mask">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $update_id ?>" name="upid"/>

                                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="package_name"  id="inputSuccess2" value="<?php echo $pkg_name; ?>">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                                        <input type="text" name="package_price" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess3" value="<?php echo $pkg_price; ?>">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                                        <input type="text" name="credits" class="form-control " id="inputSuccess4" value="<?php echo $pkg_credits; ?>">
                                        </div>

                                    <?php /*    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                                        <input type="text" name="auction" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess5" value="<?php echo $pkg_auction; ?>">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"># of Projects can be listed:</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                                <input type="text" name="projects" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $pkg_projects; ?>">
                                            </div>
                                        </div><?php */?>
                                    </form>


<form method="post" class="form-horizontal form-label-left input_mask">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Expiry:</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                                <select class="form-control" name="expiry">
                                                <?php

                                                $days = $pkg_expiry;
                                                switch ($days) {

                                                    case "30":
                                                    echo "<option value=".$days.">".$days."</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='45'>45 DAYS</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='90'>90 DAYS</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='180'>180 DAYS</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='365'>365 DAYS</option>";
                                                    break;

                                                    case "45":
                                                    echo "<option value=".$days.">".$days."</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='30'>30 DAYS</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='90'>90 DAYS</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='180'>180 DAYS</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='365'>365 DAYS</option>";
                                                    break;

                                                    case "90":
                                                    echo "<option value=".$days.">".$days."</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='30'>30 DAYS</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='45'>45 DAYS</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='180'>180 DAYS</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='365'>365 DAYS</option>";
                                                    break;

                                                    case "180":
                                                    echo "<option value=".$days.">".$days."</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='30'>30 DAYS</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='45'>45 DAYS</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='90'>90 DAYS</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='365'>365 DAYS</option>";
                                                    break;

                                                    case "365":
                                                    echo "<option value=".$days.">".$days."</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='30'>30 DAYS</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='45'>45 DAYS</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='90'>90 DAYS</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='180'>180 DAYS</option>";
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                                ?>

                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Featured Agent Logo</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                                <select class="form-control" name="Featured_Logo">
                                                <?php

                                                $pkgfeatured = $pkg_Featured_Logo;
                                                switch ($pkgfeatured) {
                                                    case 1:
                                                    echo "<option value=".$pkgfeatured.">Yes</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='0'>No</option>";

                                                    break;

                                                    case 0:
                                                    echo "<option value=".$pkgfeatured.">No</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='1'>Yes</option>";
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                                    ?>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Advertise Banner :</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                                <select class="form-control" name="Ads_Banner">
                                                <?php
                                                    $adsbanner = $pkg_Ads_Banner;
                                                switch ($pkgfeatured) {
                                                    case 1:
                                                    echo "<option value=".$pkgfeatured.">Yes</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='0'>No</option>";

                                                    break;

                                                    case 0:
                                                    echo "<option value=".$pkgfeatured.">No</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='1'>Yes</option>";
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                                    ?>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Gharxchange Site:</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                                <select class="form-control" name="website">
                                                    <?php
                                                    $pkgwebsite = $pkg_website;
                                                switch ($pkgwebsite) {
                                                    case 1:
                                                    echo "<option value=".$pkgwebsite.">Yes</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='0'>No</option>";

                                                    break;

                                                    case 0:
                                                    echo "<option value=".$pkgwebsite.">No</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='1'>Yes</option>";
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                                    ?>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Watermarked Images</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                                <select class="form-control" name="watermark">
                                                    <?php
                                                    $watermark = $pkg_watermark;
                                                switch ($watermark) {
                                                    case 1:
                                                    echo "<option value=".$watermark.">Yes</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='0'>No</option>";

                                                    break;

                                                    case 0:
                                                    echo "<option value=".$watermark.">No</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='1'>Yes</option>";
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                                    ?>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Property Video</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                                <select class="form-control" name="video">
                                                    <?php
                                                    $video = $pkg_video;
                                                switch ($video) {
                                                    case 1:
                                                    echo "<option value=".$video.">Yes</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='0'>No</option>";

                                                    break;

                                                    case 0:
                                                    echo "<option value=".$video.">No</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='1'>Yes</option>";
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                                    ?>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Featured Properties</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                                <select class="form-control" name="featured_prop">
                                                    <?php
                                                    $properties = $pkg_featured_prop;
                                                switch ($properties) {
                                                case 1:
                                                    echo "<option value=".$properties.">Yes</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='0'>No</option>";

                                                    break;

                                                    case 0:
                                                    echo "<option value=".$properties.">No</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='1'>Yes</option>";
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                                    ?>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">New Listings</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                                <select class="form-control" name="new_listings">
                                                    <?php
                                                    $newlistings = $pkg_newlisting;
                                                switch ($newlistings) {
                                                    case 1:
                                                    echo "<option value=".$newlistings.">Yes</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='0'>No</option>";

                                                    break;

                                                    case 0:
                                                    echo "<option value=".$newlistings.">No</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='1'>Yes</option>";
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                                    ?>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Hot Listings:</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                                <select class="form-control" name="hotlisting">
                                                    <?php
                                                    $hotlistings = $pkg_hotlisting;
                                                switch ($hotlistings) {
                                                    case 1:
                                                    echo "<option value=".$hotlistings.">Yes</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='0'>No</option>";

                                                    break;

                                                    case 0:
                                                    echo "<option value=".$hotlistings.">No</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='1'>Yes</option>";
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                                    ?>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Sponsored Listings</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                                <select class="form-control" name="sponsoredlisting">
                                                    <?php
                                                    $sponlistings = $pkg_sponsoredlisting;
                                                switch ($sponlistings) {
                                                    case 1:
                                                    echo "<option value=".$sponlistings.">Yes</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='0'>No</option>";

                                                    break;

                                                    case 0:
                                                    echo "<option value=".$sponlistings.">No</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='1'>Yes</option>";
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                                    ?>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Contact Agent Via Msgs:</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                                <select class="form-control" name="message">
                                                    <?php
                                                    $msg = $pkg_message;
                                                switch ($msg) {
                                                    case 1:
                                                    echo "<option value=".$msg.">Yes</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='0'>No</option>";

                                                    break;

                                                    case 0:
                                                    echo "<option value=".$msg.">No</option>";
                                                    echo "<option value='1'>Yes</option>";
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                                    ?>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-1">
                                                <button type="submit" name="update"  class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
                                                <a href="addPackages.php"><?php echo @$_GET['messages'];?></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </form>



 <?php
                                        if(isset($_POST['update'])){
                                            $pkgid = $_POST["upid"];
                                        //  $pkg_name=$_POST['package_name'];  ,auction = '".$pkg_auction."',projects = '".$pkg_projects."'
                                        //  $pkg_price=$_POST['package_price'];
                                        //  $pkg_credits=$_POST['credits'];package_name = '".$pkg_name."',package_price = '".$pkg_price."' ,credits = '".$pkg_credits."'
                                        echo    $pkg_expiry=$_POST['expiry']."<br>";
                                        echo    $pkg_Featured_Logo=$_POST['Featured_Logo']."<br>";
                                        echo    $pkg_Ads_Banner=$_POST['Ads_Banner']."<br>";
                                        echo    $pkg_website=$_POST['website']."<br>";
                                        echo    $pkg_watermark=$_POST['watermark']."<br>";
                                        echo    $pkg_video=$_POST['video']."<br>";
                                        echo    $pkg_featured_prop=$_POST['featured_prop']."<br>";
                                        echo    $pkg_newlisting=$_POST['new_listings']."<br>";
                                        //  $pkg_auction=$_POST['auction'];
                                        //  $pkg_projects=$_POST['projects'];
                                        echo    $pkg_hotlisting=$_POST['hotlisting']."<br>";
                                        echo    $pkg_sponsoredlisting=$_POST['sponsoredlisting']."<br>";
                                        echo    $pkg_message=$_POST['message']."<br>";

                                            $sql4="update packages set

                                            expiry = '".$pkg_expiry."' ,featured_agent_logo = '".$pkg_Featured_Logo."' ,ads_banner = '".$pkg_Ads_Banner."',
                                            web_url = '".$pkg_website."' ,watermark = '".$pkg_watermark."',video = '".$pkg_video."' ,
                                            featured_properties = '".$pkg_featured_prop."' ,new_listings = '".$pkg_newlisting."'  ,hot_listing = '".$pkg_hotlisting."' ,sponsored_list = '".$pkg_sponsoredlisting."' ,
                                            messages = '".$pkg_message."' 
                                            where pkg_id = $pkgid";

                                            echo $sql4;
                                            $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql4) or die(mysqli_error($con));

                                            if($result == true){
                                                header('location: managePakages.php?messages=Pakage has updated');
                                            }else{
                                                echo '  <script>
                                                            alert("There is an error | can not update Package at this time.")
                                                        </script>';
                                            }


                                        }
                                    ?>
```

This is my total code @AnthonyB

Comment: Where is $pkgid initialized ?

Comment: 'if(isset($_POST['update'])){
                                            $pkgid = $_POST["upid"];  // here the  $pkgid is initialized 
                                        //  $pkg_name=$_POST['package_name'];  ,auction = '".$pkg_auction."',projects = '".$pkg_projects."'
                                        //  $pkg_price=$_POST['package_price'];'

Comment: The error has solved 
Now the problem is. It is'nt updating the value

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you made a mistake in you sql statement.
`WHERE pkg_id = $pkgid";` will be sent as plain text in sql. So you will get syntax error. It's easy to make mistakes when you appended variables using `.` in your sql query.
You should use {} when you have to add a php variables in string. like: `WHERE pkg_id = {$pkgid}`. You have to re-format your query string.
This should do the work: 
`$sql4="update packages set
expiry = '{$pkg_expiry}' ,featured_agent_logo = '{$pkg_Featured_Logo}' ,ads_banner = '{$pkg_Ads_Banner}',
web_url = '{$pkg_website}' ,watermark = '{$pkg_watermark}',video = '{$pkg_video}' ,
featured_properties = '{$pkg_featured_prop}' ,new_listings = '{$pkg_newlisting}'  ,hot_listing = '{$pkg_hotlisting}' ,sponsored_list = '{$pkg_sponsoredlisting}' ,
messages = '{$pkg_message}' 
where pkg_id = {$pkgid};`
If the formatting dose't work, the hopefully you have bugs in your php code or in you db table.

Comment: where pkg_id = '".$pkgid."'";

I have did this, the function did work but didn't update the field

Comment: Then you have error in your code. Maybe `$pkgid` has no value. Probably its not getting any value from db. Try using $id which you used to store the `$row['pkg_id']`. I don't know but maybe you used it to store the product id.